# Loading Shapefile with Work Network creating Negative Scale

Tags: shapefile, scale

For the company I work for, we have our own servers and network we load upon start up to do our work within QGIS. However its about 50/50 when loading an outside shapefile that it works.

When I load certain shapefiles, I get this crazy scale of the shapefile that is around 1:-2,000,000,000. I re-project it to WGS 84 to match. I've tried re-projecting and saving to bring in the correct way from the start and it doesn't work. There are other shapefiles I can download and use that load up perfectly fine with no issues.

Any one have any idea what is causing this and how to get these shapefiles to load correctly?

Comment: Not a QGIS user, but my guess is that the shapefile's coordinate system is incorrect. Like it's in lat/lon but assigned a projected CS or vice versa. If you copy the shapefile locally, does it work? If so, then my guess is wrong!